# Looking to pass an entire Lambda action to a function -- not just a predicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a number of elements, all of which draw from the same data set, but which require different filters. Some need to have the value summed, others need the values counted, others need the value filtered.

So for an *incredibly simple* example, the base ViewModel class is this:

```
public class ViewModel {
  private static DataModel _data;
  public List<ListModel> CountItems { get; set; } = new List<ListModel>();
  public List<ListModel> SumItems { get; set; } = new List<ListModel>();
  public List<ListModel> FilterItems { get; set; } = new List<ListModel>();

  public ViewModel () { }
  public ViewModel (DataModel data) {
    _data = data;
    GetData(CountItems, Count);
    GetData(SumItems, Sum(x => x.Data));
    GetData(FilterItems, FirstOrDefault(x => x.Criteria == Value).Select(x => x.Data));
  }

  private void GetData<T1, T2>(T1 list1, T2 [DoSomething]) where T1 : List<ListModel> where T2 [requirements] {
    for(var i = 0; i < 12, i++){
      list1.Add(new ListModel(PrepareData(i).[DoSomething]));
    }
  }

  // This is used in many other places, it cannot be touched.
  private static IList<DataModel> PrepareData(i) => _data.[do some generic operations using the i].ToList();
}

public class ListModel {
  public string Value { get; set; }

  public ListModel() { }
  public ListModel(int? i) => Value = i is 0 || i is null ? string.Empty : i.ToString();
}
```

(The actual setup is a lot more complicated, but this is it boiled down to the essentials)

The `_data` grabs the in-memory data set, and prepares it for more than one lambda operation. So, I want to be able to do this:

```
GetData(CountItems, Count);
GetData(SumItems, Sum(x => x.Data));
GetData(FilterItems, FirstOrDefault(x => x.Criteria == Value).Select(x => x.Data));
```

And have the anonymous function behave something like this:

```
private void GetData<T1, T2>(T1 list1, T2 p) where T1 : List<ListModel> {
  for(var i = 0; i < 12, i++){
    list1.Add(new ListModel(PrepareData(i).p));
  }
}
```

That way, all I need to do is put in the Lambda chunk required, be it a `Sum()`, `Count()`, `Where()` or even a `FirstOrDefault()`, and get the appropriate single-value output. In fact, I am trying to build it as an anonymous method so that it can handle almost any input!

Please understand that I am not asking to pass in the *contents* of an action, such as what is *inside* a `.where()`, but the ENTIRE `.where()` statement itself!!

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: Corrected the above code to include a new ListModel that catches the value. This may have been screwing up some answers below.

---

EDIT 2:

Even when I do something really simple:

```
private static void GetData<T1>(T1 list1, Func<IEnumerable<Incident>, T2> p) where T1 : List<ListModel> {
  for(var i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
    var value = new int?(p(PrepareData(i)));
  }
```

It says that `T2` cannot be converted into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `Func<IEnumerable<T>,TRes>` to `GetData`:

```
private void GetData<T,TRes>(IList<TRes> list, Func<IEnumerable<T>,TRes> aggregator) where {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
        list1.Add(aggregate(PrepareData(i)));
    }
}
```

You can call this method as follows:

```
GetData(CountItems, list => list.Count());
GetData(SumItems, list => list.Sum(x => x.Data));
```

Comment: I have amended my original code to be a little more clear - the list was being forced to accept `TRes`, when it was expecting an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `GetData` should be a `Func<IEnumerable<DataModel>,int>` or you can fix the generics and make int a type parameter. 
Now GetData will look like:

```
private void GetData<T1>(List<T1> list1, Func<IEnumerable<DataModel>,T1> p)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 12, i++)
    {
        list1.Add(p(PrepareData(i)));
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like:

```
GetData(CountItems, Count);
GetData(SumItems, t => t.Sum(x => x.Data));
GetData(FilterItems, t => t.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Data == Value)?.Data)
```

EDIT

If you are expecting the result to always be an `int?` to pass to a new `ListModel`, then you can just drop the generics altogether:

```
private void GetData(List<ListModel> list1, Func<IEnumerable<DataModel>,int?> p)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 12, i++)
    {
        list1.Add(new ListModel(p(PrepareData(i))));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error on the `p(PrepareData(i))` : `Cannot convert from T1 to int`. Essentially, my lists are actually referencing a single other model which accepts an `int` (instead of a list of raw `int`s), and intellisense is asking if I want to create another constructor in that other model that accepts T1 instead of int. Which will throw all sorts of errors since T1 is only defined here.

Comment: I have amended my original post and corrected a small portion of the code. This may explain the error I am getting.

Comment: Updated answer based on your comments